# Installing Ubuntu in a pen drive instead of Hard Disk

Tags: usb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Ubuntu to an USB key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key)

I have made a bootable pendrive for Ubuntu 12. 04. Currently I am running it like a live CD by just using "try Ubuntu" option. But I want to install it. The issue is I don't want to install it in the Hard drive of my laptop, as it is an office laptop. Can I install it in another pen drive? The scenario will be like that I will use all hardware resources of my laptop as it has 8 GB RAM and I% processor. I just don't want to mess with the Hard disk. That's why I want to install Ubuntu on another 32 GB Pen drive which would act my Hard Disk. Kindly suggest the steps.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a live usb with persistence mode to save your softwares and other settings.

The easiest way I prefer under windows is [LILI](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/).

Here is an [GUIDE](http://www.howtogeek.com/65888/create-a-persistent-bootable-and-virtualized-linux-usb-drive-with-lili/)

**A Caution: Installing an OS in usb disk and using it from there is not recommended as it will reduce lifetime of the flash significantly. It is because any OS will cause large number of read-write operation with normal tasks.**

Answer (score 1):

Just create a live USB with persistence and you're done!

Answer (score 0):

Create a persistent live USB drive. Read this [wiki article](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent) to get some further info.

Answer (score 0):

Mount the pendrive to the system. Then when the installer box appears and it shows partition management, go to advanced setting and then install the ubuntu in the pendrive by creating a EXT4 system and then proceeding further.